# Image vs. BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Whenever dealing with the loading and rendering of images in Java, I have previously always used `BufferedImage`s to store and manipulate the images in memory.

However, I have recently come across a [few](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/movingsprites/) [different](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/CropImage.html) [sites](http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutorg.htm) that use the `Image` class instead of `BufferedImage` and this got me wondering - what are the differences?

I'm aware that a `BufferedImage` has a larger/optimised toolset, but does come at any cost? If so, when does this cost become noticeable? In which situations would you use an `Image` over a `BufferedImage`, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`BufferedImage extends Image`. `Image` is just a base abstract class and you can't instantiate it. Under the hood you are using `BufferedImage` or another implementation for sure.

Comment: Regarding `"Under the hood you are using BufferedImage for sure"`: not necessarily. There are other concrete implementations of Image that are often used in Java, and one cannot assume that when dealing with a concrete Image instance that it is in fact a BufferedImage.

Comment: Yes true, but in the `JavaDoc` I see the `VolatileImage` as the only another implementation. I edited my answer to be more precise, though.

Comment: Petar: There are others, some that aren't as well documented. I know because I've run into just this situation when obtaining images from Image manipulation filters. All I'm saying is that you cannot make this assumption. 1+ for your edit.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any real performance difference between directly creating a BufferedImage and a Toolkit image (java.awt.Toolkit or Image#getScaledInstance). You'll never have an actual instance of Image because it's an abstract class; you'll only be dealing with its subclasses (e.g. BufferedImage).