# Would writing an image using Image class or the class BufferedImage class work in the same way?

Tags: java

Here are my two implementations. Would both give the same result? I know that `BufferedImage` is the child class of the Image.

1. First implementation: `writeImage` takes an `Image` Object and uses `RenderedImage` in the `ImageIO.write` method.

   ```
   public void writeImage(Image img, String outputFile) {                  
       try {
           ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) img, "jpg", new File(outputFile));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
       ...
   ```
2. Second Implementation: `writeImage` takes a ``` BufferedImage`` object and uses the BufferedImage ``` object in the`ImageIO.write` method.

   ```
   public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, String outputFile){
       try {
           ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(outputFile));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
       ...
   ...
   ```

Also, try to tell what's the difference between the two ways of writing an image.

Comment: First example will fail if the `Image` isn't an instance of `RenderedImage`, so I'd say your answer is "no"

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11810370/3858121

Comment: `BufferedImage` is a descendant of `Image`, which also implements the `RenderedImage` and `WritableRenderedImage` interfaces, so I can be used any where those requirements are need.  `Image` extends from `Object` and implements nothing, so you can't guarantee it won't fail in your first example

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you think the 2nd one will work?

Comment: @ShubhamJayswal Considering the fact that `BufferedImage` implements `RenderedImage` and basically, that's how I've been using it for over six years, yes

Comment: I think this question has [been already solve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11810385/5372008). As you know `Image` is an abstract class and `BufferedImage` is its subclass, wich describes an `Image` class with an accessible buffer of image data.